# _reactNative.useState is not a function

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

hi everyone i'm just learning hooks in react native and i get an error when i try to execute the function written below. The code is:

```
    aa(){
      const [booblenavalue,setboolenavalue]=useState(false)
              useEffect(() => {             
              setboolenavalue(true)
            }, [])            
  }
```

My code don't work.My error is:" TypeError: (0 , _reactNative.useState) is not a function". How can I fix this error?

Comment: check ur useState imports, import from React library

Comment: ```import {useState} from 'react'```

Comment: share full code of this file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        import React,{useState} from 'react';

        const aa = () => {
             const [booblenavalue,setboolenavalue]=useState(false)
                                                                 
             useEffect(() => {
                 setboolenavalue(true)
             }, []);
        }

        export default aa;
```

Maybe this must be the format of your code